# 2D Javascript array sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting

Haven't done as much of Javascript as I should have done. I am trying to do some tweaks in chat made of Javascript.
This particular issue is related with user list representation.

I have got an array `nickidlst` which consists of users' id. `0=>"xxx", 1=>"yyy", 2=>"zzz"`

```
for (var i=0; i<nickidlst.length; i++)
    {
      var nickid = nickidlst[i];
      var li = this.buildNickItem(nickid);
      li.setAttribute(className, 'nickitem_'+nickid);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
```

Every user has points, which can be accessed by `this.getUserMeta(nickid, "points");`

I would like to make user ordering and listing by points in DESC order.

The idea was to make iteration to add 'points' of specific user to nickidlst array, sort it by 'points' column  and the rest code stays the same.

EDIT: It seems really easy issue. I guess I had to do more search before posting. Thank you everyone.

Comment: There is a lot missing from your code. What is "this"? Where is the variable 'ul' coming from? What is the function buildNickItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nickidlst.sort( function(a,b){
   // descending
   return this.getUserMeta(b, 'points') - this.getUserMeta(a, 'points');
});
```

[`sort` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)